# Oracle Application Express - Forms And Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm creating a database application in Oracle Application Express (Apex) by using the application builder and i have a quick question regarding forms and reports. I know how to create basic forms and reports but im aiming to do something a little more tricky. I  basically want the user to be presented with a form with the fields username and password , and after inputting the username and password i want the form to crosscheck the username and password inputted against a 'Student' table that i created with SQL and if it exists then i want the application to then bring up a report with the relevant field containing this data.

For example a user inputs 'hello' as their username and 'letmein' as the password through the form and then if it exists in the student table the application will then allow them to see the whole row of data for their specific student account only. The reason i want to do it this way is that i want the students to only be able to see their specific row of data and not any other student rows inserted in the 'Student' table obviously due to privacy reasons.

I tried to use the query on form option when creating a new page for the application but it only lets me as the developer put in the query statement and i cant do this because it has to be unique to what ever the user inputs in the 'Username' and 'Password' field on the form themselves.

Hope it makes sense as i have tried to explain in the best way possible and i have honestly been searching for a good few hours trying to find the solution but i feel their is limited Oracle Application Express material available on sites like YouTube which i normally always refer to when learning something new. I have also looked in the Oracle Application Express user docs but their is nothing that i can find that helps me to achieve the results im looking for.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want to create a login page and then a report that uses the current user as a filter?

Comment: i have a basic login page set up already, but how do i filter the user through the report as you stated?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a login page where a user is entering their username and password, the `APP_USER` value should be populated as part of your application session.  Your report, therefore, can just be

```
SELECT *
  FROM student
 WHERE username = :APP_USER
```

APEX will bind whoever the currently logged in user is automatically.

Comment: I tried to use that as a report query and it just says No data found when the report is run. Any ideas? the Student table is working fine because im able to log in through the Username and Password field that has been inserted, but why isn't this query working

Comment: @user3417643, post your query.

Comment: Ok here it is:                                                  SELECT *
FROM  STUDENT
WHERE USERNAME = :APP_USER

Comment: @user3417643 so what is entered as the username on the login screen, and what is the data in the username column in the student table, and do those 2 match up?

Comment: An example of one of the usernames on the login screen that i am using is 'student1' and it matches up correctly with the student table. Also to note i am currently using custom authentication which checks the Student Username And Password based on the student table and it definitely works as i have tried to log in with multiple users populated on the Table. Could it possibly be the fact that i am using custom authentication which is why the :APP_USER function isn't working properly ?

Comment: @user3417643 if the username in your table is stored in lowercase, then do `UPPER(username) = :APP_USER` as APP_USER is stored in uppercase

Answer (score 1):

## Customized USER Based Content in Oracle APEX

This is how I approached the implementation of the OP and a demonstration of the results.  I created two custom user accounts: "RICHARD" and "KAPLAN".  After logging into the application pages of this demo, the user will find a report as well as customized text associated to their account information.

This example uses the APEX Standard User Authentication Scheme.  This should also work with other custom authorization methods.

[image: Example custom APEX Page Content]

I also added a student name so that it would match the login name (identified by the reserved variable/item name:  `APP_USER`).  The user login name does not necessarily have to be the same as the student name.  Other approaches can be accomplished such as by providing a suitable "translation" column inside the `STUDENT` table between student name, id and login name.

This page was created to demonstrate how to call session based item values and also schema/table based references.

### User Greeting

This section is an HTML region.  The page source is plain text with some HTML tags and also a substitution variable for the `APP_USER` value:

```
 Hello There, &APP_USER. How are you today?<br>
 Your student ID number is: &P12_SID. <br>

 Welcome to your virtual classroom.
```

### Class Student List

A REPORT content type stored in a page region.  This list is a report output of information for all students stored in my sample database:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM STUDENT;
```

### Student Query Using Filter Criteria

**Hidden Page Item Approach**

```
 SELECT *
   FROM STUDENT
  WHERE ID = :P12_SID;
```

which requires...

[image: Page Item Definition by APP_USER]

```
 SELECT *
   FROM STUDENT
  WHERE NAME = :APP_USER;
```

Elsewhere in the application, where any query requires an item value to filter by `STUDENT.ID`, instead refer to the defined page item: `P12_SID`.  In this example, the "SID" (Student ID) value is passed between pages as a `HIDDEN FIELD ITEM`.

> By assigning hidden typed page items to query operations, these assigned data values become reusable throughout a page's content.  Enabling the `PROTECTED FIELD` setting for the hidden page item also prevents users from spoofing other student id values to gain access to another student's records.

### Using a PL/SQL Function to Restrict User Access

You have now seen the `STUDENT.NAME` and `STUDENT.ID` value accessed by the application login value.

### Enrollment Confirmation Page

The following tables were used to develop the output for this report.  These other supporting tables came from another Stack Overflow post with oddly similar structures and requirements.  Could this schema be part of a class assignment?

**Schema DDL Source Code**

`STUDENT_ENROLLMENT`:  This table contains the association of multiple id values that connect a `STUDENT` record to a `CLASS` record.

```
 CREATE TABLE  "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT"
    (   "CONFIRMATION_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "STUDENT_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "CLASS_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "ENROLL_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "SEMESTER_ID" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CONFIRMATION_ID") ENABLE
    )
 /
 ALTER TABLE  "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_FK" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID")
REFERENCES  "STUDENT" ("ID") ENABLE
 /
 ALTER TABLE  "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_FK2" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("CLASS_ID")
REFERENCES  "CLASS" ("ID") ENABLE
 /
 ALTER TABLE  "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT" ADD CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_ENROLLMENT_FK3" 
    FOREIGN KEY ("SEMESTER_ID")
REFERENCES  "SEMESTER" ("ID") ENABLE
 /
```

`SEMESTER_SUBJECT`:  This table connects a given class season-year and the subjects that are offered

```
 CREATE TABLE  "SEMESTER_SUBJECT" 
    (   "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "SEMESTER_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        "SUBJECT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
        PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "SEM_SUB_UQ" UNIQUE ("SEMESTER_ID", "SUBJECT_ID") ENABLE
    )
 /
 ALTER TABLE  "SEMESTER_SUBJECT" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("SEMESTER_ID")
REFERENCES  "SEMESTER" ("ID") ENABLE
 /
 ALTER TABLE  "SEMESTER_SUBJECT" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("SUBJECT_ID")
    REFERENCES  "SUBJECT" ("ID") ENABLE
 /
```

`CLASS`:  This table contains information about what class (organized by subject) is offered for each semester-year period.

```
 CREATE TABLE  "CLASS" 
    (     "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "NAME" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "SEMESTER_SUBJECT_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
    )
 /
 ALTER TABLE  "CLASS" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("SEMESTER_SUBJECT_ID")  
    REFERENCES  "SEMESTER_SUBJECT" ("ID") ENABLE
 /
```

`SEMESTER`:  This is a small dimensional field.  The combination name of academic season and year resolve to a unique id value.  To assist with the potential use of these values in List of Value queries, a `SORT_ID` value is included since the correct ordering of these values is not alpha-numeric.

```
 CREATE TABLE  "SEMESTER" 
    (     "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
      "SORT_ID" NUMBER, 
      "NAME" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL ENABLE,
       PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
    )
 /
```

### Example Output for User Customized Enrollment Reports

**This is the output demo for user/student RICHARD**

[image: Custom Enrollment Report for User RICHARD]

**This is the output demo for user/student KAPLAN**

[image: Custom Enrollment Report for User KAPLAN]

**The SQL Query Used to Define the Enrollment Report**

```
 select STUDENT.NAME as "STUDENT NAME",
     STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.CONFIRMATION_ID as "CONF ID",
     SEMESTER.NAME as "SEMESTER YEAR",
     SUBJECT.SUBJECT_NAME as SUBJECT,
     CLASS.NAME as "CLASS NAME",
     STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.ENROLL_DATE as "ENROLL DATE" 
  from SUBJECT SUBJECT,
     CLASS CLASS,
     SEMESTER_SUBJECT SEMESTER_SUBJECT,
     SEMESTER SEMESTER,
     STUDENT STUDENT,
     STUDENT_ENROLLMENT STUDENT_ENROLLMENT 
  where SEMESTER_SUBJECT.SEMESTER_ID = SEMESTER.ID
     and SEMESTER_SUBJECT.SUBJECT_ID = SUBJECT.ID
     and SEMESTER_SUBJECT.ID = CLASS.SEMESTER_SUBJECT_ID
     and STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.SEMESTER_ID = SEMESTER_SUBJECT.SEMESTER_ID
     and STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.CLASS_ID = CLASS.ID
     and STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.STUDENT_ID = STUDENT.ID
     and STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.STUDENT_ID = :P2_SID
```

> **NOTE:** the "Student ID" parameter, `P2_SID` is populated by the redirect command associated with the navigation button on P12 (the demo start page).  `P2_SID` is also a hidden, protected page item.

### Connecting the Start Page to the Enrollment Report

Use a navigation link, preferably a BUTTON type (but it doesn't matter).

1. Choose the action of: "REDIRECT" to the page in the application for the enrollment report.
2. Set the TARGET page item for `STUDENT_ID` to the value set for the item `STUDENT_ID` derived in the START page.  Remember, session attribute `APP_USER` and page item `STUDENT_ID` are not the same, but their relation is defined by how the application authentication scheme is set up and also the structure of the `STUDENT` information table.

### Closing Comments

It isn't clear what has already been attempted to customize the user experience based on non-user-selectable values.  Still, speaking of this solution in a general sense is a useful guide in APEX design and functionality.

If queries and their presentation through report pages are involved, the developer can take a session property, such as a "user name" and apply it into a report SQL query definition, either directly or through the use of "page items".

If there is a need to use these parameters elsewhere within the application, navigation elements such as "region buttons"  have the ability to transfer derived parameters from one page to the next.